# how to use a single expression to select the second largest number in a 3 numbers set in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the largest and second largest number in a set of three numbers by using python language, but I was stuck in how to write a code in a single expression of the body.
Ask for help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show some code or original question.

Comment: set as set in python or just a set of numbers?

Comment: `sorted(list(set(lst)), reverse=True)[:2]`?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you needed

> heapq.nlargest(n, iterable[, key])
>
> ```
> Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument
> ```
>
> that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the
>   iterable: key=str.lower Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key,
>   reverse=True)[:n]

```
In [1]: nums = [1, 8, 2, 23, 7, -4, 18, 23, 42, 37, 2]

In [2]: import heapq

In [3]: heapq.nlargest(2,nums)
Out[3]: [42, 37]

In [4]: heapq.nlargest(2,nums)[1]
Out[4]: 37
```

Comment: A bit of overkill to use a heap, but why not? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
s = {2,3,1}
s.discard(min(s))

{2, 3}
```

This will work for a set of 3 elements: to keep only the second largest and the largest, you simply discard the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_numbers = [5,1,7] #would be the same for set(list_of_numbers)
sorted(list_of_numbers)[::-1][:-1] #single expression providing two largest numbers from list of 3 numbers
#result: [7, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple explanation to find the second largest number from the array list.
You can change the logic accordingly.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = len(arr)
arr.sort()
for i in range(0, x-1):
    if arr[i] == max(arr):
        arr.remove(arr[i])

arr.remove(max(arr))
print(max(arr))
```